# Discord Api: Create message with multiple images?

Tags: discord

I am creating a message with the discord API:
https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message

This is the data I am posting:

```
$data = [
    'content' => $content,
    'embed' => [
        'title' => $thread->title,
        'description' => $post->message,
        'url' => $url,
        'author' => [
            'name' => $thread->username,
            'url' => $thread->user_url,
            'icon_url' => $icon,
        ],
        'image' => [
            'url' => $image1->url,
        ]
    ],
];
```

All this works great.

However, I've noticed that some people have managed to write bots that post messages with multiple embedded images on it. How would I go about getting this done?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still curious: I don't know if it's officially documented anywhere or not (I didn't see it on a quick glance, at any rate), but I ultimately stumbled across the solution in [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions/3253#discussioncomment-953023): Embeds on the same message with the same URL will be displayed as one embed, with the images from any beyond the first one displayed inside the initial embed. (Though, all properties besides `image` are ignored on following embeds.)

It's worth noting that it doesn't always display all of them, however; for me, it displays four on desktop, and only one on mobile, even though the limit on embeds per message is theoretically ten.

For example, the following JSON code:

```json
{
  "embeds": [
    {
      "type": "rich",
      "title": "Example Embed",
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "description": "A demonstration of Discord's embed append feature.\n[Source for the images used.](https://autocode.com/tools/discord/embed-builder/)",
      "color": 46079,
      "image": {
        "url": "https://polybit-apps.s3.amazonaws.com/stdlib/users/discord/profile/image.png?1"
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "description": "Other fields seem to be ignored, currently.",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-janeth.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "title": "As you can see here.",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-jacklyn.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "A shame.",
          "value": "But it is what it is.",
        }
      ],
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-jacob.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "author": {
        "name": "There's a limit of 10 embeds per post, btw",
      },
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-keith.png"
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-nestor.png"
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Not hitting that here, though.",
          "value": "Also, 8MB max total in one message.",
          "inline": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-will.png"
      },
      "timestamp": "2021-11-03T18:11:13.718Z"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/landing/onboarding/mini-scott.png"
      },
      "color": 10000
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/social/opengraph-embed-builder.png"
      },
      "footer": {
        "text": "None of this is visible besides `image`. Even `thumbnail`."
      }
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/",
      "image": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/branding/favicon-01.png"
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": "https://content.public.files.stdlib.com/shared/static/images/anonymous.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Renders on desktop as:

[image: Screenshot of the embed on desktop]

And on mobile as:

[image: Screenshot of the embed on mobile]

This seems to be what autogenerated embeds for sites such as Twitter use, so I imagine it's the "official" way to do it.